# Does the Pentacon Six TL have a built-in light meter?

Tags: metering, medium-format, old-cameras

Does the Pentacon Six TL have a light meter built in?
If not, how does one measure light with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The viewfinder on this camera is interchangeable. The waist-level (top-down) finder does not have metering. There are also non-metering prism finders, and version with a light meter built-in — the "TTL metering prism". ("TTL" for *through the lens*, of course.)

If you did not have a built-in meter, you would either use an [external light meter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48047/how-to-select-a-light-meter) or judge exposure based on experience. (See also: [How did people calculate exposure in the pre-light meter era?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/64510/calculating-exposure-pre-light-meter-era))

Comment: Ahh, the days of interchangeable viewfinders!

Comment: @mattdm So viewing from the 'top' viewer, is not consider prism am I right? i.e. you need external light meter?

Comment: @neversaid Yeah. Updated.

Comment: Be also aware that the Pentacon TTL metering prism only works with the original matte glass focus screens. If you have a Pentacon fresnel or a third party focus screen (which are usually much brighter than the original ones), the TTL metering prism won't measure correctly.